# Is there anyway in bootstrap to show navbar hamburger at 992px screen size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to show the bootstrap navbar Hamburger at md(992px) Screen. Below is my code.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the behaviour of "collapse" or "navbar-collapse" classes. Though it's not recommended because those are bootstrap classes. 
You should encounter a @media command in the CSS code, there specify your desired pixels.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

By default, nav collapse at `992px`. Override it to whatever size you want it collapse. However, it is better to customise the source code of Bootstrap, but i am not sure if there is a specific break-point variable for navbar-collapse.

---

I copied this code from Bootstrap.css. You need to put it in your custom CSS.

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg {
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg>.container,
  .navbar-expand-lg>.container-fluid {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">` add one more class `navbar-expand-md` for the md devices. Now it will work.